# Insert a row only if doesn't exist without getting its id

Tags: mysql

I followed this [tutorial](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-upsert-in-mysql/) with 'INSERT IGNORE' first and 'INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' then. But it doesn't work.
I'm using NodeJS to get some data from an API, and store these data into a mySQL database. Before storing data, I want to know if this row already exists.
The ID is AUTO_INCREMENT and I d'ont know this one. Instead of using async/await or promises in NodeJS, I wanted to treat this point with mySQL without knowing the ID.

I tried this one but it adds a new row with a new ID instead of another row already exists:

```
INSERT INTO test (nom, date, heure) VALUES ('123456', '2018-08-23', '10:45:00') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE nom='123456', date='2018-08-23', heure='10:45:00';
```

After that, I tested this one, same result:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO test (nom, date, heure) VALUES ('123456', '2018-08-23', '10:45:00')
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The new row is inserted with a new id. What else did you expect to happen?

Comment: I don't want to insert a new row of the others fields are the same as ones of the previous into the table.

Comment: Is there a unique index or constraint for the other columns?

Comment: No, there is not. The only constraint is a unique ID AUTO_INCREMENT and some fields that can not be null.

Comment: Then the row is inserted without problem.

Comment: So you need a unique key with nom, date, heure so the system knows when it is the same row and it is a duplicate

Comment: I don't want to add a row if all of the other fields except the ID are the same. I don't know the ID from my NodeJS side, I only want to perform this action with SQL.

Comment: Consider storing date and time as a single entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a unique index for the 3 columns:

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD UNIQUE un_index(nom, date, heure);
```

Then execute:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO test (nom, date, heure) VALUES ('123456', '2018-08-23', '10:45:00');
```

If the 3 values already exist, the row will not be inserted.